# Why I am getting 'SslHandler removed before handshake completed message' while consuming a service using AsyncHttpClient in Java

Tags: asynchttpclient

I used DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig to configure connection timeout and SSL context.

```
DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder clientBuilder = Dsl.config()
                    .setConnectTimeout(100)
                    .setKeepAlive(true)
                    .setSslContext(sslContext);
```

Next, I created an AsyncHttpClient object using Dsl.

```
AsyncHttpClient client1 = Dsl.asyncHttpClient(clientBuilder);
```

Next, I hit the service as shown below.

```
AsyncHttpClient client1 = Dsl.asyncHttpClient(clientBuilder);
            BoundRequestBuilder postRequest = client1.preparePost(BASE_URL)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("x-api-key", transactionKey)
                    .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                    .setBody(reqObj);
ListenableFuture<Response> responseFuture = postRequest.execute();
```

When I try to read the response from the service I get the 'SslHandler removed before handshake completed' exception.

I should read the JSON response from the service after sending a post request but I get the 'SslHandler removed before handshake completed' exception.

Comment: Above Issue was raised when I upgrade async-http-client-1.7.5 JAR to async-HTTP-client-2.12.3 JAR